# mysql workbench 6.3 hangs on queries on percona mysql 5.6

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, mysql, mysql-workbench

So I have three computers:

1. Windows 10 with MySQL Workbench 6.0
2. Windows 7 with MySQL Workbench 6.3
3. Windows 10 with MySQL Workbench 6.3

I also have three MySQL servers.

1. version=5.5.35-33.0, version_comment=Percona Server (GPL), Release 33.0
2. version=5.1.73-0ubuntu0.10.04.1-log, version_comment=(Ubuntu)
3. version=5.6.27-76.0, version_comment=Percona Server (GPL), Release 76.0, Revision 5498987

Computer # 1 can connect to all three servers and run queries without a problem. Computer # 2 and # 3, however, hang when I do `SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 2000` on server # 3. Like on servers # 1 and # 2 the duration / fetch column gets updated pretty quickly. It goes from `? / ?` to (for example) `0.078 sec / ?` and then to `0.078 sec / 1.029 sec`. But on server # 3 it just stays at `? / ?`. And clicking on the Stop icon doesn't stop it either - it just causes the spinning mouse cursor icon to appear and then I have to force kill Workbench, which is rather annoying.

The thing both computers # 2 and # 3 have in common is that they're running MySQL Workbench 6.3.

In Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor -> SQL Execution -> SELECT Query Results I have the "Limit Rows" checkbox disabled.

Any ideas? Should I just try to find and download and older version of MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of MySQL Workbench 6.3 (all my machines are 64-bit machines). Same result. I tried the 64-bit version of Workbench 6.2. Same thing. The newest version that it seems to work with is the 32-bit version of Workbench 6.1 (the only version that's available for download at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/6.1.html)

That said, I guess Percona [doesn't officially support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15483992/569976) MySQL Workbench.